# This issue should be resolved now or it should have been resolved now

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

Sometimes we receive an office email from a native English speaking HR Admin as follows [as an example]:

```
We are currently experiencing issues with printer.....
```

Then sometimes later a follow-up email comes in as follows:

```
This issue should now be resolved and you should be able to ....
```

**Question**: Should the above follow-up email say `This issue has now been resolved ...` or it's ok to what Admin's follow-up email says. It could be that I, being a non-native English speaker, missing something here.

**NOTE**: I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the “should now be” version?

Comment: @Jim I'm used to reading `has now been completed`, `has been submitted`, `your request has been received` etc., etc. So, being not a native English speaker, the email message in question got me a bit curious and got me thinking maybe I should learn something from the context of the email so I could use the same in my writings, conversations etc. But wanted to hear from experts first, in case I'm missing something. I've edited my question.

Comment: The following phrase, following Michael's answer, will probably make sense now, but since it's such a common phrase, I thought it useful to include it in this comment. If someone were to say that something "should work", this means that we are not certain that it will work, but are pretty confident that it will. I would also have a look into the definition 1.1 in the OED here https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/should, since you may run into usage where it is used to express the fact that someone believes something is a right, for example 'we should be able to do whatever we wish'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use 'should' when we confidently expect something to be the case, but have not yet checked. I put the cake in the oven forty-five minutes ago; it should be cooked now. I have adjusted the printer settings/refilled the paper tray/changed the toner and the issue should now be resolved/you should be able to print now.

> 1.1 Indicating a desirable or expected state. ‘by now pupils should be able to read with a large degree of independence’

[Should](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/should)